# S4: Quinn vs Jinx

Tags: league-of-legends

What is the best way to lane against a Jinx as Quinn?

What are Jinx's weaknesses? She seems to be able to easily cs (like 100%) whil I (as quinn) can only get 90% or so.

How can I keep up with Jinx's CS?
When is the best time to go for trades?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-iBfaPu7zQ watch and learn, I don't know how this game turns out because I didn't watch the video.. But I learned the most from watching streams ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

*Laning Phase:*

- Play passive-aggressive and wait for the right moment to go in.
- If their supporter isn't there just go ham on her and kill her.
- You have to Initiate (50% slow) if you wanna go all-in.

*General stuff:*

- Only use your ultimate defensively or for faster objectives.
- You can 1v1 most champions. Do it!
- Take an aggressive supporter if you can.
- Splitpushing is a great strenght of you.
- Avoid playing Quinn in serious games until you have fully mastered her. (She's not a weak champion in  general but she is weak if you haven't mastered her)

**In-Depth**

You don't have to only know all the strengths and weaknesses of Jinx but also those of Quinn.

If you take a look at the tier list, Jinx is definitely higher ranked and also from personal experience I have to say that Jinx is alot stronger. But the list focusses only on carry potential of a whole game and not on laning.

The laning phase of those two is basically equal. Jinx is just a bit better when it comes to harrassing an enemy and you are better at going all-in. If it comes to a 1v1 you can easily take the upper hand against Jinx because of your Blind and Stronger single target damage.

Now to cover the laning phase: If someone with the same range as your champ has more farm than you it simply means that he can farm better. Of course Jinx has a very fast attack animation but if you practice a bit with quinn you can easily be on the same level or even higher when it comes to CS. For complete lane dominance you should take a supporter with you that has some all-in potential and hard CC. Jinx has absolutely no gapclosers and her only defense mechanisms are her Flame Chompers and passive (well maybe her Zap but that thing has a huge cast time). If you play Leona/Quinn vs Jinx/Randomsupport you can basically kill her by going all-in on her once. If you have a Passive supporter the lane is extremely hard to win. Another thing when she is harrassing you is your blind. That really is the counter to every autoattacking champion and it lasts 1.5 seconds (that's huge!!) so really try to blind her if she is autoattacking you. Also if she is attacking you with her rocket (700 range) keep in mind that you can still close the gap between you and her since your leap has a range of 750. And always start with your vault if you want to go in. It slows the enemy for 50% and makes hitting skillshots easier for your support.

For Teamfights things look a bit worse for you. Having an ability that grants 700 range is a lot more useful in teamfights than in the laning phase. Usually you won't get past their bruisers while she can shoot all the high priority targets from the back line. Also Jinx has a lot of teamfighting abilities while your skillset is basically built for 1v1ing opponents. So for teamfights follow these rules:

- Only use your ultimate for Repositioning/Hunting down single targets. Once you're in meele range you will get stunned and killed.
- Keep your jump as an escape mechanism as long as the enemy bruiser is still alive.
- Don't be too afraid of bruisers (That doesn't mean that you should underestimate them!). You can handle most of them because your single target damage is basically as high as Vaynes in lategame.
- If you see that you will lose teamfights go splitpushing. Your just as good as Jinx if not better.

Comment: Play passive-aggressive? I don't know if that's going to work against Jinx. For example, a typical exchange: Quinn: "Does that make you feel better if you hurt me? You don't have to do this, you know. Leave me alone, that hurts!" Jinx: "She's such a loser, always ready to cry" *continues shooting Quinn with Fishbones*

Comment: Mostly really good advice here.  The only thing I would stay away from is saying that you use that 700 range in teamfights to shoot the people behind the bruisers.  As an adc, it is basically your job to shoot/kite the closest person to you.  Before going for the high damage targets you always want to kill the bruisers/tanks that are jumping on you about 95% of the time.  Otherwise you will be placing yourself in a bad position for a quick death.

Answer (score 0):

Will Quinn is pretty much the best ADC i play and uasually i get over 15 Kills per game. i don't have a screenshot or whatever, but try to take my advice..

- Have a good support champion that can stun like (Blitzcrank, Leona or Tariq).
- Don't engage without your Q, and try to harass her with you Q too.
- Critical Chance Build.